# Disadvantages of this jQuery plugin pattern to add public methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, design-patterns

I'm currently working on a pretty big plugin I'm wondering if this pattern for adding public methods has any disadvantages and if so what are those?

**EDIT:** To clarify, with this method the advantages I can see are that you can use any private variable available in the plugin's scope and you can chain the methods easily. What are the disadvantages I can't see? It's been working fine but I'm not sure if this is recommended for big plugins in terms of scalability.

Here's the code simplified:

```
;(function($){

  $.fn.myplugin = function () {

    var self = this

    var publicMethods = {      
      one: function () {
        ...
        return self
      },
      two: function () {
        ...
        return self
      },
      three: function () {
        ...
        return self
      }
    }

    for (var m in publicMethods)
      self[m] = publicMethods[m]

    return self

  }

}(jQuery))

// Usage
var $myplugin = $('#foo').myplugin()
$myplugin.one().two().three()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it has disadvantages.

1. You're polluting the jQuery internal namespace with *all* of your `publicMethods`. This means that `one()`, `two()` and `three()` can also be called on other jQuery objects - after you call `.myplugin()` -  this might lead to unintended results?
2. It highly un-maintainable to keep your code structured in this weird way - an object internal to a function. Why not just add your `publicMethods` to `$.fn`, since it's basically what you're trying to achieve?

I advise to make `one()`, `two()` and `three()` accessible only inside the `myplugin()` scope, so that you can do stuff like `$('#foo').myplugin().one()` but not `$('#foo').one()`.

Comment: But does it really create a conflict? I made a quick fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/jw6x2/. How would you do it differently? Could you provide an example?

Comment: I've done some more tests and it seems that your first point is not happening. I updated the fiddle. The second point is debatable, why do you think is unmaintainable?

Comment: Assuming there's more to OP's plugin, it might make sense to expose public methods in this way, but the method names would have to be pretty unique, otherwise it might conflict with another plugin that has the same named methods. Namespace 'em, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219635/jquery-plugin-namespacing-functions)

Comment: I agree with your cons (+1) but can you flesh them out a little better?